# How can I shuffle the rows of a large csv file and write the result to a new csv file without using too much memory?

Tags: python-3.x, csv

So if I have a csv file as follows:

```
User  Gender
 A    M
 B    F
 C    F
```

Then I want to write another csv file with rows shuffled like so (as an example):

```
User  Gender
 C    F
 A    M
 B    F
```

My problem is that I don't know how to randomly select rows and ensure that I get every row from the original csv file. For reference my csv file is around 3gb. If I load my entire dataset into a dataframe and use the random package to shuffle it, my PC crashes due to RAM use.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the easiest (and fastest) is to use `shuf` in bash!

```
shuf words.txt > shuffled_words.txt
```

(I know you asked for a Python solution, but I am going to assume this is still a better answer)

To programmatically do it from Python:

```
import sh
sh.shuf("words.txt", out="shuffled_words.txt")
```

Comment: What exactly does sh.shuf do? I can't seem to find documentation on it.

Comment: @mrnovice `sh` just is a wrapper around bash commands. So everything coming after `sh.` will be a bash shell command.

Comment: I tried using it, but got an error saying sh is only supported on mac and linux (I'm using windows)

Comment: @PascalVKooten what if my CSV has header and I do not want header to be shuffled?

Comment: What if the .csv file has a header? How to shuffle everything except the first row?

Comment: You could first do `head -n 1 words.txt > shuffled_words`, then to remove the first line `sed -i '1d' words.txt` and then `shuf words.txt >> shuffled_words.txt`

Answer (score 0):

- Create an array of lines as file positions of line starts, by reading the file once as random access or memory mapped file. The array has one extra entry with the file length,
  so the line *i*  holds the bytes `[array[i], array[i+1]>`.
- Shuffle the indices 0 .. number of lines - 1.
- Now you can use random access positioning (seek) to read a line buffer.

Comment: Suppose my csv file had 1000 lines (excluding header). Then this array you mention would store the numbers 1 to 1000 and there would be an extra entry with the number 1000 on the end.  Then I shuffle this array, excluding the last entry. Is this correct so far? I don't really understand what you mean by random access positioning though.

Comment: No, you need a permutation array storing indices 1 to 1000 shuffled (or 0 to 999 if zero based indices). Pseudo code: `for j in 1 to 1000, i = permutation[j]; output line (i)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the chunk_size argument to csv in chunks

`df_chunks = pandas.read_csv("your_csv_name.csv", chunk_size=10)`

Then you can shuffle only the chunks so it takes less memory

```
for chunk in df_chunks:
    do stuff
```

Then you can concat them and save it into another csv :

```
new_df = pandas.concat(new_chunks)
new_df.to_csv("your_new_csv_name.csv")
```

If you have memory issue, while you create new_chunks don't forget to erase old one as you don't want them to be left in RAM for no reason, you can do it with
`chunk=None`

Comment: I don't think this solution would work for my dataset, since there are two categories of data, one is in the top half of the file, the second in the bottom half. So this method would not properly shuffle between these two categories. Apologies, I probably should have included that information in my question.