# How to shuffle very large .csv files with headers in python?

Tags: python-3.x, linux, bash, csv, shuffle

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57973511/how-can-i-shuffle-the-rows-of-a-large-csv-file-and-write-the-result-to-a-new-csv/) post, using `shuf` is the fastest way:

```
import sh
sh.shuf("words.txt", out="shuffled_words.txt")
```

However, this code shuffle the header as well. My file has a header and I don't want the header to shuffle in the data.

Comment: How big is your file? You can shuffle easily inside of Python !

Comment: I cannot load it in memory, there are multiple files each 100GB+

Comment: Does this answer your question? [bash - shuffle a file that is too large to fit in memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40814785/bash-shuffle-a-file-that-is-too-large-to-fit-in-memory)

Answer (score 2):

Copy the content of the file into another file without the header:

```
with open("words.txt") as infile, open("words-nohead.txt", "w") as outfile:
    for i,line in enumerate(infile):
        if i: outfile.write(line)
```

Then shuffle the headerless file. Then copy the first line of the first file and the headerless file into shuffled_words.txt (I think you can use `sh.cat()` for this) and remove the interim files.

Actually, you do not need Python for this. Bash alone suffices:

```
head -n 1 words.txt > shuffled_words.txt    
tail -n+2 words.txt | shuf >> shuffled_words.txt
```

Bear in mind that `shuf` reads the whole file in memory, anyway. You must have enough memory for the file.

Comment: Thanks! How to stop ```shuf words-nohead.txt``` from printing the outputs in the terminal? It's a big file and printing it will cause issues I think

Comment: See the updated answer. Bear in mind that `shuf` reads the whole file in memory, anyway. You must have enough memory for the file.

Comment: Well the data size is 100GB+ and I'm not sure if this will work on the data. I will try it though and accept the answer if it works. Thanks

Comment: Ask yourself if you really need to shuffle the lines. If so, you will probably need an out-of-memory shuffler, which is an entirely different thing.